# Присвоить input класс active если поле не пустое

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Вот HTML

```
<input type="number" placeholder="" />
```

Вот JS

```
$("input").on("keyup", function(e) {
    if($(this).val() != "") {
        $(this).addClass("active");
    }
});
```

В input[type='number'] можно ввести только цифры. Но символ "е" тоже вводится. Нужно сделать проверку если поле не пустое то присвоить ему класс active. Если случайно введен символ "е" то класс active тоже нужно присвоить. Нужно чтобы класс присваивался всегда если поле не пустое. Как это сделать?

Comment: А что будет если ввести 1e1 и потом нажать на стрелку вверх у инпута?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что будет правильнее ставить обработчик на событие *input*, а не на *keyup*:

```js
$('input').on('input', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active', ($(this).val() != '' && !/e/gi.test($(this).val())));
});
```

```css
.active { background-color: cyan; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="number" placeholder="" />
```

Comment: Изменил условия. Не совсем точно объяснил в первый раз.

Comment: Создал правильный вопрос    https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1345574/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81-active-%d1%83-inputtype-number-%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%bd-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b9

Answer (score 0):

Получилось как-то так. Но если нажать на стрелку вверх-вниз, то экспанента исчезнет. И нужно либо применять замену значения с регуляркой, либо кастомные стрелки делать.

```js
$("input").on("keyup", function(e) {    
    $(this).removeClass("active");    
    
    if($(this).val() != "" || e.keyCode === 69) {          
        $(this).addClass("active");
    }
});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" placeholder="" />
```

Comment: Изменил условия. Не совсем точно объяснил в первый раз.

Comment: @Denis тогда не ясно в чём проблема. если пустое removeClass, если не пустое addClass и всё

Comment: inputtype='number'] при наличии в нем символа "e" думает что там его нет.

Comment: @Denis ну тогда `if($(this).val() != "" || e.keyCode === 69) {  ` )) чуть костыльно правда)) либо взять ответ UModeL и сделать там `||`  без знака `!`

Comment: Думаю закрою. Не точно написал этот вопрос. Извининте.

Comment: Создал правильный вопрос    https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1345574/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81-active-%d1%83-inputtype-number-%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%bd-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b9