# Не удалять класс active у input[type='number'] если он не пустой

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Если в `input[type='number']` введен символ "е", то это поле считается пустым. Поэтому, при *mouseup* вне элемента, у него убирается класс "active".

```js
$(document).on("mouseup", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  hide_element = $(".input_wrapp");
  if (!hide_element.is(e.target) &&
    hide_element.has(e.target).length === 0) {
    $(".input_wrapp").each(function() {
      if ($(this).find("input").val() == "") {
        $(this).find("input").removeClass("active");
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="input_wrapp">
  <input type="number" />
</div>
<div class="input_wrapp">
  <input type="number" />
</div>
<div class="input_wrapp">
  <input type="number" />
</div>
```

Нужно чтобы, если `input[type='number']` был не пустым, то класс "active" не убирался. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Учитывая [предыдущий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1345456/265406), проясню один момент:

- Элемент `<input>` с `type="number"` имеет встроенную проверку введённого значения. Именно эта валидация не позволяет вводить символы отличные от цифр (за исключением символов: `+` `-` `.` `,` `e`) и возвращает пустую строку, при любом некорректном значении. По этой причине, **невозможно** получить реальное текущее введённое значение, пока оно не будет приведено к валидному виду.

Если же задача состоит в том, чтобы просто знать, что поле не пустое, то можно воспользоваться проверкой [отображения подсказки](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/:placeholder-shown) в поле - `:placeholder-shown`. В этом случае, наличие данного псевдокласса будет истинным, только в случае отсутствия любых символов (т.е. поле ввода будет полностью пустым).

Таким образом, можно проверить, введены ли какие-либо символы, даже если `value` возвращает пустую строку из-за некорректного значения.

- Важно! Для реализации вышеописанной проверки, у элемента `<input>` должен присутствовать атрибут `placeholder`, который будет содержать по крайней мере один символ (допускаются непечатные символы и пробел, на случай, если подсказка не должна быть видимой).

Думаю, что следующий пример удовлетворяет основному требованию:

> *Нужно чтобы, если input[type='number'] был не пустым, то класс "active" не убирался.*

*Все значения для **class** и **placeholder** произвольны и указаны лишь для наглядного примера.*

```js
$('input').on('input', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active', !$(this).is(':placeholder-shown'));
  console.log(this);
}).trigger('input');
```

```css
.active { background-color: cyan; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="number" placeholder="field_1" class="active" />
<input type="number" placeholder="field_2" class="second" />
<input type="number" placeholder="field_3" />
```

Comment: При клике вне инпута с значением "е" класс active все равно убирается.

Comment: @Denis: не наблюдаю подобного о_0